# MediaCapture VideoDeviceController properties capabilities randomly supported

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

On `MediaCapture` initialization I try to set some properties (Contrast, Zoom, Brightness), but only if supported by the host device.

```
var _captureMgr = new MediaCapture();
            await _captureMgr.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings{
                    VideoDeviceId = devices[currentDevice].Id,                    
                });

            await _captureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();  

if (_captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.Supported)
            {
                brightnessSlider.Minimum = _captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.Min;
                brightnessSlider.Maximum = _captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.Max;
                brightnessSlider.StepFrequency = _captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.Step;
                brightnessSlider.Value = (brightnessSlider.Minimum + brightnessSlider.Maximum) / 2;
            }
```

At first time the Brightness Slider is currently initilized, in fact `_captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.Supported` is **true**.

At second time (after `_captureManager.Dispose()`) the App executes the same code, but `_captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.Supported` is **false**.

This sounds weird considering the fact that while debugging if I pause before the check, the second try works too. It seems to be some delay between check and real reinitialization, but a `Task.Delay(millis)` doesn't work.

Is there some issue in my *async/await* logic?